# Can't access the Django server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker-compose

At firt time it worked totally fine but it is showing this issue now:

```
app$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 03, 2017 - 17:28:43
Django version 1.11.4, using settings 'aggregator.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

It says its running but I can't Access it on that address. What could have been possibly wrong?

my docker-compose file:

```
    version: "2"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/data/postgres

  backend:
    build: .
    command: gosu app bash
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - pyenv:/python
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

volumes:
  pyenv:
  pgdata:
```

Comment: Post your compose file and check the published ports. Try to connect to container's IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: What error do you encounter and where does docker-compose come into this?

Comment: @fernandezcuesta "Try to connect to container's IP address instead of localhost."--I'm running docker-compose app on local host

Comment: @JonClements I think I'm getting this error because of  docker file

Comment: @fernandezcuesta what do you mean by 'try to connect container's IP address instead of localhost'?

Comment: try to run your django `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: I mean try to connect from the docker host to the container instead, even if the port is exposed and you should be able to reach it with localhost.

Comment: @BearBrown I got this error when I tried to run it on 0.0.0.0:8000  DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '0.0.0.0:8000'. You may need to add '0.0.0.0' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Comment: Can somebody please help me through this? I'm trying to solve this since last 2 days. @BearBrown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For development, you can try setting this in `settings.py`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

and then start your server locally by running:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Man, I was a beginner and was frustrated with this setup, finally worked like charm

Comment: @Brown Bear Would you check out the similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76408272/10452700) here kindly?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question of

> What could have been possibly wrong?

A number of things:

1. The mapping of your parts is incorrect. Your application is mapping to another port other than 8000. Check which port your application is mapped to. Not by checking the output of `python manage.py runserver`, because that is not the command you run in your container. Check the logs of your container.
2. When your command `gosu app bash` is run, there is an error. Check the output of `docker logs backend`.
3. You could be running the `docker-compose up -d` command incorrectly.

Post the out put of the logs if you want more information.