# Django localhost load

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, ubuntu, containers

I am running Ubuntu container on windows 10 host. I installed Django on Ubuntu container and now when I run Django (python3 manage.py runserver) I cannot view Django logo on IE host browser. I tried loading browser with URL such http://localhost:8000, Ubuntu container IP on port 8000, but no luck.

I could connect to container using curl either via localhost or container IP address.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you expose `8000` port in your container? you can't access any urls served by django or just the static files only?

Comment: Enix thanks for quick reply.  I run the following commands in order:  Docker run –I –expose=8000 ubuntu bash and then installed the Django. Then ran python3 manage.py runserver container-ip:8000. But I cannot access http://container-ip:8000 to see the welcome page on the IE browser? BTW curl container-ip:8000 does work.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026116/cant-access-the-django-server-at-http-127-0-0-18000